how to expand a string in bash so that it evaluates to a pipeline
Suppose I have the following variable in a bash script cmd='echo hi | wc'.
Since I forgot how many characters are in the string "hi", I want to run cmd.
I expected this be as simple as typing $cmd at a prompt and letting the shell's infamous implicit word splitting take care of the rest.
But it seems that the one time I actually WANT word splitting, bash tries to protect me and the output is simply hi | wc.
I stared at this in utter confusion for a bit, and eventually decided to try set -x.
Turns out that bash is running echo hi '|' wc.
That is, bash implicitly added quoting for me!
On one hand, this is usually great.
The shell scripts of the world would be in worse shape without this feature.
But that still leaves me with the unsolved problem of how to actually run the command echo hi | wc.

there'll be feedback on the negatives wrt doing this in general. Howver, if you alias , as in alias cmd='echo hi | wc' will do what you think it should

this is in the context of a bash -c invocation ... do aliases work in that context?  I think not by default but they can be enabled?

eval "$cmd" will do what you want.

Make sure you only do this with a cmd that you control. If it can come from an untrusted source, it's dangerous.

See BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!. The very short form is that you should be storing commands in functions, not variables (you can export functions to the environment, so it is possible to make them runnable by code invoked with bash -c; bash can also automatically serialize functions for you to generate strings you can pass over ssh or such).

Also BashFAQ #48: Eval command and security issues

...for Barmar's "if it can come from an untrusted source", treat cmd="echo $something | wc" as an untrusted source if the content of something wasn't vetted by a human; if something='$(rm -rf ~)' (and it's perfectly legal to put the string $(rm -rf ~) inside a filename, f/e) then you're going to have a very bad day.

do you mean : cmd='echo hi|wc',
bash -c "${cmd}"
1       1       3

@ticktalk yes, that is indeed what I meant

@CharlesDuffy ... thanks for note about functions ... I was about to write a long comment here about why that I can't use functions in my particular situation because of a complication that I didn't mention in the original question, but after writing most of it I realized that the complication has a simple workaround and I totally can use functions after all.

@CharlesDuffy Okay, I'm no longer so sure that the workaround is actually simple... I might have to resort to the technique described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63220591/evaluate-variable-at-time-of-function-declaration-in-shell

or maybe not ... all I need to do is export a few crucial variables over ssh

@MarkVY, ssh somehost "$(declare -p var1 var2); $(declare -f func1 func2); func1". If you'd asked about your real problem in the first place we could have pointed you that way days ago.

The answer to How to have single and double quotes in a scripted ssh command? demonstrates several relevant techniques.

thanks!  I confess that it had never even occurred to me to to use functions until AFTER you mentioned it... my question was phrased in terms of the solution I was already pursuing to my problem... but yesterday the code I wanted to pass got even more complicated so I figured it's finally time to take your function idea more seriously so I only then began seriously thinking about what needs to be local and what needs to be remote and what needs to be both

just want to say that switching to functions has made my life so much better ... I feel like I have space to think about what I'm doing instead of constantly thinking about quoting rules
